# Request-based Localization of Razor pages in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages, asp.net-core-localization

My application is hosted by a server located in the US. I live in the UK.
When I open the page locally I can see the proper format of the date `dd/mm/yyyy` based on the place I live, however, when I deploy the app to Azure US app service, and open it in the same web browser I can see the `DateTime` format changed to the US culture `mm/dd/yyyy`
[image]

The part of the code from the razor page .cshtml:

```
<br>
        <h2>Subscription</h2>
        <hr />

        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subscription.StartDate)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-9" id="StartDate">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subscription.StartDate)
            </dd>
            ...

            <dt class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subscription.EndDate)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-9" id="EndDate">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subscription.EndDate)
            </dd>

        </dl>
```

I played with changing the way how I display the date, I had an idea to apply `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and I ended up with sth. like

`@(Model.Subscription.EndDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

but this still doesn't help. I understand that the page is generated on the server, however, is there any way how I can display the `StartDate`/`EndDate` based on the browser's settings rather than server once?
Maybe I need to use some javascript extension to achieve what I want? 
Is it possible to define a global rule to display all the dates in the client's format for the whole RazorPages application?
Cheers

Comment: Did you look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#localization-middleware?

Comment: @haim770 thanks for the idea, I'm just about checking if it works :)

Comment: I've just applied the idea to the application and it seems to work fine. Middleware is so powerful in .net core :D I think I can accept this as an answer, so if you want to, you can create an answer-post and I'll approve. Thanks for the help, shalom brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the equivalent of `enableClientBasedCulture` in classic ASP.NET:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" ... />
</system.web>
```

For modern ASP.Net applications (that are [Owin](http://owin.org/)-based) you need to rely on the [Localization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#localization-middleware) to achieve (roughly) the same results.

In your `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
});
```

Some differences though:

- The classic `enableClientBasedCulture` only uses the HTTP `Accept` header to determine the culture, while the new middleware tries from the querystring and cookies as well.
- The classic `enableClientBasedCulture` would map to any requested culture that is supported by the OS, while the new middleware requires all supported cultures to be pre-defined.

For a more detailed discussion, see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2649